# sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []uuid.UUID, a slice of array

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

working in some insertion in postgresql where the table struct is

```
CREATE TABLE user_subservices(
    user_id        uuid,
    subservice_id  uuid
);
```

im passing an array of user_id and a single subservice_id

`q:=INSERT INTO user_subservices (user_id,subservice_id) VALUES  (unnest(Array[$1]::uuid[]),$2)`

passing `[]uuid.UUID` for `$1` and single uuid for `$2`

I'm using gorm to run those query

```
err := db.dbConn.DB.Debug().Exec(q, users, Id).Error
```

In debug i got:

```sql
INSERT INTO user_subservices (user_id,subservice_id) VALUES  (unnest(Array['[8bf23c03-4112-4097-a352-b567d5a00052 9epolf4b-ff4a-49ef-bojd-2890ff3a7yhf]']::uuid[]),'00uj9000-0100-0120-0000-034000000068')
```

it's not passing as a proper array to insert

any solutions to insert??

Comment: `unsupported type []uuid.UUID` means that `gorm` does not support the type `[]uuid.UUID`, in other words `gorm` does not know how to encode `[]uuid.UUID` before sending the data to the postgres backend. To be able to use custom types you'll need to declare them first and then you'll need to have them implement an interface that `gorm` supports (e.g. `sql.Scanner`, `driver.Valuer`).

Comment: @mkopriva for the insights .it finally worked

Answer (score 0):

From the debug log, this is the SQL query used on the operation:

```sql
INSERT INTO user_subservices (user_id, subservice_id)
VALUES (
    unnest(Array('[8bf23c03-4112-4097-a352-b567d5a00052 9epolf4b-ff4a-49ef-bojd-2890ff3a7yhf]')::uuid[]),
    '00uj9000-0100-0120-0000-034000000068'
)
```

It is an incorrect query, the correct one should be:

```sql
INSERT INTO user_subservices (user_id, subservice_id) 
VALUES (
    unnest(Array['8bf23c03-4112-4097-a352-b567d5a00052', '9epolf4b-ff4a-49ef-bojd-2890ff3a7yhf']::uuid[]),
    '00uj9000-0100-0120-0000-034000000068'
)
```

See the placement of quote character (`'`) and comma (`,`), also `Array()` is incorrect syntax, it should be `Array[]`.

---

Apart from that, I see another issue with your query. Two of the UUIDs are not valid:

- `9epolf4b-ff4a-49ef-bojd-2890ff3a7yhf`
- `00uj9000-0100-0120-0000-034000000068`

You might get an error `SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "00uj9000-0100-0120-0000-034000000068"` even after fixing the query. However it can be easily solved by providing valid UUIDs

Comment: these ids i changed before posting it here kindly ignore the ids

Comment: tried it if i manully run in terminal its working if i pass a param its not working thats my issue

Comment: could be an issue on the gorm side when the query was constructed. maybe for this particular case you can use raw SQL query on the gorm

Comment: in raw query can we pass 2 params?

Comment: looks like you already used raw query. let me try to check it

Comment: @noob which package you used for `uuid.UUID` type? next time I recommend to post the relevance source code because it is easier for us to check.

Comment: `Array[$1]::uuid[]` is wrong @noob, it should be just `$1::uuid[]`.

Comment: @noob also `[ ... ]` is not valid postgresql syntax for array __string literals__. Postgres uses `{ ... }` for array string literals, i.e. `'{uuid1, uuid2}'::uuid[]` will work, `'[uuid1 uuid2]'::uuid[]` will not. You should convert the Go type `[]uuid.UUID` to a type that knows how to encode itself into a valid PostgreSQL uuid array __string literal__.

Comment: @novalagung yes im using uuid.UUID,sure

Comment: @mkopriva if i use $1::uuid[] also same error getting

Comment: @noob as I already stated in my follow up comment: *"You should convert the Go type []uuid.UUID to a type that knows how to encode itself into a valid PostgreSQL uuid array string literal."*